# How to pass an input as list to a reusable GitHub Actions workflow?

Tags: github-actions

I have this GitHub Actions reusable workflow:

```
name: "Reusable workflow which need to pass on multiple runners"
on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      runner:
        required: true
        type: string
jobs:
  build:
    name: Build image
    runs-on: ${{ inputs.runner }}
```

I use two values for my two runners: `"ubuntu-22.04"`, and `[self-hosted, v3]`. However the second one does not work if I pass it as a string in the calling workflow:

```
name: "e2e: calling workflow"
on:
  push:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - master
jobs:
  call-workflow-passing-data:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/e2e-common.yml
    with:
      runner: [self-hosted, v3]  # This does not work
```

Is there a way to pass a list to a reusable GitHub Actions workflow input?

Comment: Can you use [`runs-on: ${{ fromJSON(inputs.runner) }}`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#fromjson)? See e.g. https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/11692#discussioncomment-2914324.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @[jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe) suggested in the comments, you can indeed use the [fromJSON(value)](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#fromjson) function to resolve your issue.

> Returns a JSON object or JSON data type for `value`. You can use this function to provide a JSON object as an evaluated expression or to convert any data type that can be represented in JSON or JavaScript, such as strings, booleans, null values, arrays, and objects.

In that case, you would need to update your reusable workflow implementation to use:

```
name: "Reusable workflow which need to pass on multiple runners"
on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      runner:
        required: true
        type: string
        default: "['ubuntu-latest']" # this default value could be useful here

jobs:
  build:
    name: Build image
    runs-on: ${{ fromJSON(inputs.runner) }} # fromJSON function used here
```

In that case, your `main` workflow calling the reusable would look like below:

```
name: "e2e: calling workflow"
on:
  push:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  call-workflow-passing-data:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/e2e-common.yml
    with:
      runner: "['self-hosted', 'v3']" # note the " and ' here
```

Interesting references:

- [(Github Community) Part 1 - #11692](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/11692#discussioncomment-3541856)
- [(Github Community) Part 2 - #11692](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/11692#discussioncomment-2914324)